# Maxscript Filein not working in Macroscript

Tags: maxscript, rollout

I wrote a macroscript as a .ms that calls other scripts yesterday and it worked great.
When I tried using it today, the filein for calling other scripts is working for all of my scripts but one.  That script that is called is also a macroscript.  It's pointing at the correct file, I know this because I use doesFileExist.  It's unable though to call any of the global variables.
So when I'm trying to create a new window and add the global rollouts to them from the script that is called I get

```
-- Type error: addRollout requires RolloutClass, got: undefined <<"Worked out"
"is valid is true"
-- Error occurred in IOMorpher.pressed(); filename: C:\Users [etc] Autodesk\3dsMax\2015 - 64bit\ENU\usermacros\ToolsScript-ToolsScript.mcr; position: 5653; line: 117
--  Frame:
--   testString:     "\\[called script location] \calledscript.ms"
--   isValid: true
>> MAXScript Rollout Handler Exception:
-- Type error: addRollout requires RolloutClass, got: undefined <<
```

I'm not sure why the rollouts as well as the other global variables are undefined after the filein today instead of yesterday.

EDIT: deleted the mcr and am just using the .ms for the script.  Still not getting the global variables from the script that is a macroScript.

Comment: You need double slash 'c:\\folder\\file.ms' or : 'c:/folder/file.ms'.